# Keypress event keyCode works with spacebar, but not the letter F

Tags: javascript

Spacebar works fine, but I don't understand why pressing the letter `f` doesn't print to `console.log`?

```
<button type="button" id="keyboard">Keyboard</button>

<script>
    var kbd = document.getElementById( "keyboard" );

    kbd.focus();

    kbd.addEventListener( "keypress", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode == 32 ) {
            if ( player.getPlayerState() == 1 ) {
                console.log('pressed spacebar 1');
                player.pauseVideo();
            }
            else {
                console.log('pressed spacebar 2');
                player.playVideo();
            }
        }
        if ( event.keyCode == 70 ) {
            console.log('pressed letter f');
        }
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:

With `keypress` the correct keyCode is `102`. With `keydown` the correct keyCode is `70`. At least according to my tests. Spacebar works with `32` for either.

Comment: use " if else " instead of  " if "  in event.keyCode == 70

Comment: there must be an error that breaks the code before it gets to `if(event.keyCode == 70)`

Comment: @novonimo—that wont make any difference.

Comment: Maybe because I'm sending the keypress to a `button`? Spacebar has some utility for a button, but letter `f` doesn't.... I'm stumped.

Comment: if you have separate keyboard along with laptop, the keycode coming is 102

Comment: `F` is 102! I went to three reference sites and they all said 70! Put your answer below @uthistran, or I can just delete this Q.

Comment: i will answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F is 102!. The below will work

```
<button type="button" id="keyboard">Keyboard</button>

<script>
var kbd = document.getElementById( "keyboard" );

kbd.focus();

kbd.addEventListener( "keypress", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 32 ) {
        if ( player.getPlayerState() == 1 ) {
            console.log('pressed spacebar 1');
            player.pauseVideo();
        }
        else {
            console.log('pressed spacebar 2');
            player.playVideo();
        }
    }
    if ( event.keyCode == 102 ) {
        console.log('pressed letter f');
    }
});
```

Added [JSFilldle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmrwozeL/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Keypress is deprecated.

Change "keypress" to "keydown".

keycode 70 with "keypress" is an uppercase F, you can confirm this by holding down shift and f, while keycode 102 is a lowercase F.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event).

Comment: Well that's interesting. With `keypress` it's `102`. With `keydown` it's `70`.

Comment: I added an explanation.